# Group epimorphism between finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, epimorphisms

Suppose $\Phi:G_1\to G_2$ is an epimorphism from a *finite* group $G_1$ to $G_2$. Assume $G_1$ can be generated by m elements and let $\{z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_m\}$ generate $G_2$. Then. can we say there exists a set of elements $\{g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_m\}$ in $G_1$ which generate $G_1$ and $\Phi(g_i)=z_i$ for every $i=1,2,\ldots,m$?
If it holds, how can we say that the pre-images of $z_i$'s, where $i=1,2,\ldots,m$ will generate group $G_1$? Is there any direct way to prove it?

What I have tried is:

$\Phi$ is a surjective map, so we take a set of preimages of $\{z_i:i= 1,2,\ldots,m\}$, say $\{\bar g_1,\bar g_2,\ldots,\bar g_m\}$ in $G_1$. Suppose $K=\ker\Phi$. Here $\Phi$ need not be injective. Now, we consider a set $\{\bar g_1K,\bar g_2K,\ldots,\bar g_mK\}$. If we can show that this set generates the quotient group $G_1/K$ (I don't know how to prove it...), then there exists a generating set $\{g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_m\}$ of $G_1$ such that $g_i\in\bar g_iK$ (I have used a result from a German paper which states: "Let $G$ be a group generated by $d$ elements. If $N$ is a finite normal subgroup, then, for every generating set $\{\bar e_1,\bar e_2,\ldots,\bar e_d\}$ of $G/N$, there exists a generating set $\{e_1,...,e_d\}$ of $G$ such that $e_i\in\bar e_iN$." Here, I am providing a [link](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mana.19550140406) to that paper.
And this gives $\Phi(g_i)=z_i$ for every $i=1,2,\ldots,m$.

Is this approach correct? and if it is then how to prove the set $\{\bar g_{1}K,\bar g_{2}K,...,\bar g_{m}K\}$ generates $G_{1}/K$ or any hint ?

Thank you.

Comment: Take $G_1=\mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z_2, G_2=\mathbb Z_2, \Phi(u,v)=u$ for $u,v\in\mathbb Z_2$ is surjective, and $m=1, z_1=1\in\mathbb Z_2$. Then $z_1$ generates $G_2$, but there isn't a $1$-element set in $G_1$ generating it (as $G_1$ is not cyclic). Thus I think your statement doesn't hold.

Comment: I mean, any morphism to the single-element group is an epimorphism, that group is generated by its identity, but clearly the preimage doesn't generate anything.

Comment: In the statement we have given that $G_{1}$ can be generated by m elements. So in your case $G_{1}$ can't be generated by single element. So $G_{1}$ is not satisfying given hypothesis. So, we can't imply the statement will not hold.

Comment: Your argument appears correct, That the $\bar{g_{i}} K$ do generate $G_{1}/K$ comes from the fact that $\Phi$ induces an isomorphism between $G_{1}/K$ and $G_{2}$.

Comment: Yes I agree with Andreas Caranti. The argument is correct, and neither of thw two suggested counterexamples satisfies the hypotheses of the question. I did not know the result you cite about generation - I am guessing that it doesn't work when $N$ is not assumed to be finite.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yeah, I think you are right. I'll try to think counter example.@Andreas Caranti Okay. I got it. So, my task is to show in an isomorphism generators maps to generators. Thank you.